# Default, platform specific, Bazel flags in bazel.rc

Tags: bazel

I was wondering if its possible for platform-specific default Bazel build flags.

For example, we want to use `--workspace_status_command` but this must be a shell script on Linux and must point towards a batch script for Windows.

Is there a way we can write in the `tools/bazel.rc` file something like...

```
if platform=WINDOWS build: --workspace_status_command=status_command.bat
if platform=LINUX build: --workspace_status_command=status_command.sh
```

We could generate a .bazelrc file by having the users run a script before building, but it would be cleaner/nicer if this was not neccessary.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, kind of. You can specify config-specific bazelrc entries, which you can select by passing `--config=<configname>`.

For example your bazelrc could look like:

```
build:linux --cpu=k8
build:linux --workspace_status_command=/path/to/command.sh
build:windows --cpu=x64_windows
build:windows --workspace_status_command=c:/path/to/command.bat
```

And you'd build like so:

```
bazel build --config=linux //path/to:target
```

or:

```
bazel build --config=windows //path/to:target
```

You have to be careful not to mix semantically conflicting `--config` flags (Bazel doesn't prevent you from that). Though it will work, the results may be unpredictable when the configs tinker with the same flags.

Answer (score 1):

A better way of doing this has been added since you asked--sometime in 2019.

If you add
`common --enable_platform_specific_config` to your .bazelrc, then `--config=windows` will automatically apply on windows hosts, `--config=macos` on mac, `--config=linux` on linux, etc.

You can then add lines to your .bazelrc like:

```
build:windows --windows-flags
build:linux --linux-flags
```

There is one downside, though. This works based on the host rather than the target. So if you're cross-compiling, e.g. to mobile, and want different flags there, you'll have to go with a solution like envoy's (see other answer), or (probably better) add transitions into your graph targets. ([See discussion here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/14673) and [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/14669). "Flagless builds" are still under development, but there are usable hacks in the meantime.) You could also use the temporary platform_mappings API.

References:
[Commit that added this functionality.](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/59755455034a998cdedfb7b086aea3ad78419381)
[Where it appears in the Bazel docs.](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--enable_platform_specific_config)

Answer (score 0):

Passing --config to all commands is tricky, it depends on developers remembering to do this, or controlling the places where Bazel is called.

I think a better answer would be to teach the version control system how to produce the values, like by putting a `git-bazel-stamp` script on the `$PATH`/`%PATH%` so that `git bazel-stamp` works.

Then we need `workspace_status_command` to allow commands from the PATH rather than a path on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to do this is to wrap your cc_library with a custom macro, and pass hardcoded flags to copts. For full reference, look at [envoy_library.bzl](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/main/bazel/envoy_library.bzl).

In short, your steps:

1. Define a macro to wrap cc_library:

```py
def my_cc_library(
  name,
  copts=[],
  **kwargs):
  cc_library(name, copts=copts + my_flags(), **kwargs)
```

2. Define `my_flags()` macro as following:

```py
config_setting(
    name = "windows_x86_64",
    values = {"cpu": "x64_windows"},
)

config_setting(
    name = "linux_k8",
    values = {"cpu": "k8"},
)


def my_flags():
  x64_windows_options = ["/W4"]
  k8_options = ["-Wall"]
  return select({
        ":windows_x86_64": x64_windows_options,
        ":linux_k8": k8_options,
        "//conditions:default": [],
    })
```

How it works:

Depending on --cpu flag value `my_flags()` will return different flags.
This value is resolved automatically based on a platform. On Windows, it's x64_windows, and on Linux it's k8.
Then, your macro `my_cc_library` will supply this flags to every target in a project.