# Choosing platform-specific default --config from bazelrc

Tags: bazel

**Is there a mechanism to select a default config based on the platform or the environment variable?** For example:

```
common --config=$DEFAULT_CONFIG
```

I'm working on a project which uses `bazelrc` configurations to specify default build and test flags for separate platforms. It looks something like this:

```
build:macos --compiler=clang
...
build:linux --compiler=gcc
...
build:windows --compiler=msvc
...
```

This would be really useful for a multi-platform CI setup and in general would avoid having to type `bazel <command> --config=<some config> <target>` every time.

Related question: [Default, platform specific, Bazel flags in bazel.rc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48159516/default-platform-specific-bazel-flags-in-bazel-rc)

Comment: Are you familiar with toolchains and platforms? It sounds like that would really help you. I can add a more complete answer with links if you haven’t chased down that lead

Comment: Thanks for the pointer :) I'm generally aware of them but haven't gone down that lead, how would they help in this case?

Answer (score 3):

There is now! If you add
`common --enable_platform_specific_config` to your .bazelrc, then `--config=windows` will automatically apply on windows hosts, `--config=macos` on mac, `--config=linux` on linux, etc.

You can then add lines to your .bazelrc like:

```
build:windows --windows-flags
build:linux --linux-flags
```

There is one downside, though. This works based on the host rather than the target. So if you're cross-compiling, e.g. to mobile, and want different flags there, you *could* wrap all the library rules you use in macros, or (probably better) add transitions into your graph targets. ([See discussion here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/14673) and [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/14669). "Flagless builds" are still under development, but there are usable hacks in the meantime.) You could also use the temporary platform_mappings API.

References:
[Commit that added this functionality.](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/59755455034a998cdedfb7b086aea3ad78419381)
[Where it appears in the Bazel docs.](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--enable_platform_specific_config)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, that's what [toolchains](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/toolchains.html) are for.